# Error attempting to view files and logs for Bluemix app

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I want to view the Files and Logs for my Bluemix application, but when I select this from the Overview page for my app, it just shows the message:

> BXNUI0045E: Could not retrieve files or logs for the 'XXX' application using instance '0'. See the Troubleshooting topics in the IBM Bluemix Documentation to check service status, review troubleshooting information, or for information about getting help.

I looked at the Troubleshooting topics but found nothing helpful.  What is this message trying to tell me, and how can I fix this problem so that I can see Files and Logs for my app?

Answer (score 3):

If your application failed to start or crashed, the Bluemix UI can not be used to retrieve the files and logs. I recommend you use the command line tool.

If the application failed to start or crashed, you can get logs by:

`cf logs <appname> --recent`

If the application started and running properly, you can view the files (including any logs the server or application writes) by:

`cf files <appname>`
`cf files <appname> <path>`

Comment: Thanks Ram, but the Bluemix UI fails even for a running app.  I've submitted a problem ticket.